# Moving python code to separate file

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm having trouble moving my functions into a separate file as they access a wxpython gui.
The functions are from "onSaveMovieFile" to "LogThis"

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: us-ascii -*-
# generated by wxGlade 0.6.3 on Fri Jul 22 11:53:07 2011
"""
    Copyright (c) 2011 Mitchell Lafferty <coolspeedy6 at gmail dot com>

    This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
    the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
    (at your option) any later version.

    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
    GNU General Public License for more details.

    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
    along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
"""
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE,self.OnClose)
        self.Stop_Never.Bind(wx.EVT_TOGGLEBUTTON, self.onToggleNever)
        self.On.Bind(wx.EVT_TOGGLEBUTTON, self.OnToggleOn)
        self.Compile_every_now.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.Compile)
        self.Stills_Select.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onDirStills)
        self.Movie_Select.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onSaveMovieFile)
        self.Cap_every_SpinCtrl.Bind(wx.EVT_SPINCTRL,self.OnSpinUnlimited)
        self.Comp_every_SpinCtrl.Bind(wx.EVT_SPINCTRL, self.OnSpinUnlimited)
        self.Framerate_SpinCtrl.Bind(wx.EVT_SPINCTRL, self.OnSpinUnlimited)
        self.Comp_Frames_SpinCtrl.Bind(wx.EVT_SPINCTRL, self.OnSpinUnlimited)
        self.InitSizeAndQuality()

    def onSaveMovieFile(self, event=None):
        dlg = wx.FileDialog(
            self, message="Save file as ...",
            defaultFile="Timelapse.avi",
            wildcard="Video files (*.avi)|*.avi",
            style=wx.SAVE
            )
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            path = dlg.GetPath()
            if not path.endswith(".avi"): path += ".avi" # NOTE: Not safe?
            self.Movie_Input.SetValue(path)
        dlg.Destroy()

    def onDirStills(self, event=None):
        dlg = wx.DirDialog(self, "Choose a directory:",
                           style=wx.DD_DEFAULT_STYLE
                           ## | wx.DD_DIR_MUST_EXIST
                           ## | wx.DD_CHANGE_DIR
                           )
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            path = dlg.GetPath()
            if not path.endswith("/"): path += "/" # NOTE: Not safe?
            self.Stills_Input.SetValue(path)
        dlg.Destroy()

    def onToggleNever(self,event=None):
        self.Stop_Date.Enable(not self.Stop_Never.GetValue())

    def OnToggleOn(self,event=None):
        self.Snap()
        self.Compile()

    def Snap(self,event=None):
        """
        NOTE: returns cause late work,
        if "self.CheckDueDate()" is at bottom
        this makes it execed deadline also,
        late work should be a user option.
        """
        # Haha, "Snapshot and save" sounds like a photo discount store!
        print "Snapshot and save code here..."
        if not self.Latework.GetValue(): self.CheckDueDate() # NOTE: does not cause late work

        try:
            if self.On.GetValue():
               CapUnit =  self.Cap_every_append.GetSelection()
               CapVal  =  self.Cap_every_SpinCtrl.GetValue()
               CapVal = self.Time2seconds(CapVal,CapUnit)
               print CapVal

               if CapVal  > 0:
                   CapTimer  = threading.Timer(CapVal,self.Snap)
                   CapTimer.start()

        except Exception as err:
            print "Error:", err
            self.On.SetValue(False)

        if not self.On.GetValue():
            if 'CapTimer'  in vars():
                CapTimer.cancel()
                return

        path = self.Stills_Input.GetValue()
        file = ""

        if not os.path.exists(path):
            print "Error opening: " + path
            return
        try:
            capture = cv.CreateCameraCapture(-1)
            if not capture:
                print "Error opening: Camera device"
                return

            #cvSetCaptureProperty( capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640 );
            #cvSetCaptureProperty( capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480 );
            frame = cv.QueryFrame(capture)
            if frame is None: return
            file = time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S", time.gmtime())
            file = path + "TS" + file + ".png"
            cv.SaveImage(file, frame)
        except Exception as err:
            print "Error getting/saving frame: ", err

        if os.path.isfile(file):
            try:
                self.Picture.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap(file, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY))
            except Exception as err:
                print "Can't show picture!: ", err
        else:
            print "Error opening: " + file
            return

        print file
        if self.Latework.GetValue(): self.CheckDueDate() # NOTE: causes late work
        ##if 'CapTimer'  in vars(): CapTimer.start()

    def Compile(self,event=None):
        print "Compile into movie code here.."
        if not self.Latework.GetValue(): self.CheckDueDate() # NOTE: does not cause late work

        try:
            if self.On.GetValue():
               CompUnit =  self.Comp_every_append.GetSelection()
               CompVal  =  self.Comp_every_SpinCtrl.GetValue()
               CompVal = self.Time2seconds(CompVal,CompUnit)
               print CompVal

               if CompVal  > 0:
                   CompTimer  = threading.Timer(CompVal,self.Compile)
                   CompTimer.start()

        except Exception as err:
            print "Error:", err
            self.On.SetValue(False)

        if not self.On.GetValue():
            if 'CompTimer'  in vars():
                CompTimer.cancel()
                return

        file = self.Movie_Input.GetValue()
        path = self.Stills_Input.GetValue()
        TimeApart = self.Time2seconds( self.Comp_Frames_SpinCtrl.GetValue(), self.Comp_Frames_append.GetSelection())
        if not os.path.exists(path):
            self.LogThis("opening: " + path,None,False)
            return
        try:
            fps = self.Framerate_SpinCtrl.GetValue()
            if fps<=0: fps = 10
            frames = glob.glob(path + "TS*.png")
            writer = cvCreateVideoWriter(file, -1, fps, is_color=1) # frame_size=-1
            for i in range(len(frames)):
                if TimeApart > 0:
                    frames[i] = re.search('TS(.*)\.png', frames[i]) # find correct file
                    frames[i] = frames[i].group(0)                  # grab date
                    frames[i] = mktime(time.strptime(frames[i], "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")) # make into timestamp
                    frames[i] += TimeApart                                       # add to timestamp
                    frames[i] = path + time.strftime("TS%Y%m%d%H%M%S.png", time.gmtime(frames[i])) # make path+file place

                if os.path.isfile(frames[i]):
                    self.ImageResize(frames[i])
                    cvWriteFrame(writer, frames[i])
        except Exception as err:
                self.LogThis("Can't make movie: " + str(err),None,False)
        if self.Latework.GetValue(): self.CheckDueDate() # NOTE: causes late work
        ##if 'CompTimer' in vars(): CompTimer.start()

    def CheckDueDate(self):
        if self.Stop_Never.GetValue(): return
        print "Timer duedate code here..."
        selected = self.Stop_Date.GetValue()
        month = selected.Month + 1
        day = selected.Day
        year = selected.Year
        date_str = "%4d%02d%02d" % (year, month, day)

        #?print date_str
        #?print time.strftime("%Y%m%d", time.gmtime())
        if date_str <=  time.strftime("%Y%m%d", time.gmtime()):
            print "Deadline reached!"
            self.On.SetValue(False)
            if 'CapTimer'  in vars(): CapTimer.cancel()
            if 'CompTimer' in vars(): CompTimer.cancel()
            ##self.OnToggleOn()

    def Time2seconds(self,time,unit):
        # errors "long int too large to convert to c long"
        #  unit == (anything else)  # seconds 1
        if unit == 1:
            time *= 60              # minutes 60
        elif unit == 2:
            time *= 60 * 60         # hours 60 * 60
        elif unit == 3:
            time *= 24 * 60 * 60    # days 24 * 60 * 60
        elif unit == 4:
            time *= 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 # years 365 * 24 * 60 * 60
        return time

    def OnSpinUnlimited(self,event=None):
        obj = event.GetEventObject()
        obj.SetRange(0, obj.GetValue() + 100)

    def OnClose(self,event=None):
        if 'CapTimer'  in vars(): CapTimer.cancel()
        if 'CompTimer' in vars(): CompTimer.cancel()
        self.Destroy()

    def ImageResize(self,file):
        """##
        try:
            from PIL import Image
        except Exception as err:
            print 'We need This module!: ', err
            self.Size_Combo.Enable(False)
            self.Quality_SpinCtrl.Enable(False)
            self.label_7.Enable(False)
            return
        ##"""
        try:
            OldImage = Image.open(file)
            # pil_image.size pil_image.format pil_image.mode
            SizeVal = self.Size_Combo.GetValue()
            Size = SizeVal.split('x', 1);
            if Size[0] <= 0 or Size[1] <= 0: return
            NewImage = OldImage.resize((Size[0], Size[1]), Image.ANTIALIAS)
            NewImage.save(file,quality=Quality_SpinCtrl.GetValue())
        except Exception as err:
            self.Error_GUI_Print_Log('resize: ' + str(err),None,False)

    def InitSizeAndQuality(self):
            try:
                from PIL import Image
            except Exception as err:
                self.LogThis('We need This module!: ' + str(err))
                self.Size_Combo.Enable(False)
                self.Quality_SpinCtrl.Enable(False)
                self.Size_and_Quality_label.Enable(False)
    def LogThis(self,msg,level=None,LOUD=True):
        if level == None: level = logging.ERROR
        LEVELS ={}
        LEVELS[logging.DEBUG]=_('Debug')
        LEVELS[logging.INFO]=_('Info')
        LEVELS[logging.WARNING]=_('Warning')
        LEVELS[logging.ERROR]=_('Error')
        LEVELS[logging.CRITICAL]=_('Critical')
        print LEVELS[level],":",msg
        if LOUD:
            try:
                wx.MessageBox(msg,LEVELS[level])
            except:
                pass
        if NoLog: return #'NoLog'  in vars() and 
        logger = logging.getLogger('YaTLC')
        hdlr = logging.FileHandler('./YaTLC.log')
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
        hdlr.setFormatter(formatter)
        logger.addHandler(hdlr)
        #logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        logger.log(level,msg)
        #logger.shutdown()
```

*PS: I fixed it, all I did was put the function in a different file, imported it, and replaced some "self's" with the name of the different file*

Comment: to attach code, copy paste it into the question and indent it with 4 spaces or select the code and hit the curly-braces icon

Comment: Simply paste the code into the text box while you are writing your question, select it all, and hit the `{}` button on the toolbar.

Comment: To attach code is useful. To attach *all* your code is not. Please, if possible, attach the minimal script that reproduces the problem you have.

Comment: It's difficult to tell what's being asked here.  Do you receive stack traces when you move the functions?  Most likely, the references to `self` will need to be changed because the new function will not be a method of the previous instance.  A better idea of why you're refactoring might help as well -> is there a specific reason you need to move the functions to a new file?

Comment: @g.d.d.c I just want to keep my code organized and seperate from the gui

Comment: @linuxrules I can not test your code as you took out the class definition. What I meant before is that you should eliminate all pieces of code unrelated with the problem you have, to produce a simplified but **functional** test script. This also helps you to isolate the failing pieces of code and maybe to solve the problem by yourself. p.ex., the copyright notice is obviously unrelated with your problem and it is not necessary to post it, but probably also the logging stuff, etc. You should also describe your problem explicitly. Saying "I have a problem" says nothing. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I fixed it, all I did was put the function in a different file, imported it, and replaced some "self's" with the name of the different file

Comment: @linuxrules, Now I think I understand your question. Look my answer

Comment: @joaquin Thanks a million thats exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you are using wxglade for the design of you gui.
The best procedure is to keep the code from glade untouched in a file. Then you import and subclass the wxglade created class in a new file. There you write all your Bind() and functions there.

For example suposse this is your wxglade autogenerated file:

mygui.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: iso-8859-15 -*-
# generated by wxGlade HG on Tue Jul 26 20:03:16 2011

import wx

# begin wxGlade: extracode
# end wxGlade



class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        # begin wxGlade: MyFrame.__init__
        kwds["style"] = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.text_ctrl_1 = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, "", style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)

        self.__set_properties()
        self.__do_layout()
        # end wxGlade

    def __set_properties(self):
        # begin wxGlade: MyFrame.__set_properties
        self.SetTitle("frame_1")
        # end wxGlade

    def __do_layout(self):
        # begin wxGlade: MyFrame.__do_layout
        sizer_1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer_1.Add(self.text_ctrl_1, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        self.SetSizer(sizer_1)
        sizer_1.Fit(self)
        self.Layout()
        # end wxGlade

# end of class MyFrame
```

Then in your application:

myaplication.py

```
import wx
from mygui import MyFrame

class MyApplication(MyFrame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kargs):
        MyFrame.__init__(self, *args, **kargs)

        ##**put here all your Bind()**


    #**then put all your methods here:**

    def onSaveMovieFile(self, evt):
        ----------------

    def LogThis(self, evt):
        ----------------


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = MyApplication(None)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```